# Adding multiple subreports to a Master report on one page (if possible)

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtrareport

I'm constructing an aggregate report that reports on many different file types and parameters. This consists of many sub-reports (an unknown number, user-selectable). Currently I am taking the first report, and designating it master, and then using `master.Pages.AddRange(subreport.Pages)` for each sub-sequent report.

However this creates poor flow, as sometimes I have reports that take up only a third of the page in terms of actual data, but insist on using the whole page. Is there anyway to force the sub-reports to share pages if they can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this task, create a separate report layout, and then use subrepors (XRSubreport) to embed two reports into a single document. For instance, refer to this documentation article: [How to: Create a Report with Side-by-Side Subreports](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument4787)

Comment: Thanks, this lead me to the solution I ended up using. I now have a report with 3 sub-reports on it. I then check the total height of each incoming subreport, and if it plus the current master report height is less than the height of the page, I add it to the detail report. After I run out of room, or 3 sub-reports are added, I CreateDocument the detail report, and then add the page(s) of the detail report to my master report, and reset the detail report and pagesize. If you have headers and footers, you will also need to hide them as needed. Hope this helps someone else.